# How to merge rows by same value in different columns using Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame, something like this:

```
Id  Col1    Col2    Paired_Id
1   a       A
2   c       B
A       b   1
B       d   2
```

I would like to merge the rows to get the output something like this. Delete the paired row after merging.

```
Id  Col1    Col2    Paired_Id
1   a   b   A
2   c   d   B
```

Any hint?

So:
Merging rows (ID) with its Paired_ID entries.
Is this possible with Pandas?

Comment: Please reformat your tables. It isn't obvious looking at the underlying markdown which cells belong to which columns. If you're asking how to merge, see below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming NaNs in the empty cells, I would use a [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) with a `frozenset` of the two IDs as grouper:

```
group = df[['Id', 'Paired_Id']].apply(frozenset, axis=1)

out = df.groupby(group, as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
  Id Col1 Col2 Paired_Id
0  1    a    b         A
1  2    c    d         B
```

Comment: It's been a long time since I've seen frozenset :-)

Comment: @Corralien actually I think `np.sort` might be more efficient

Comment: 2 times faster for np.sort.

Comment: @Corralien which exact code did you use?

Comment: Just a timeit, the groupby doesn't work as it :-)

Comment: Yes that's what I thought, there is an additional cost to convert the 2D array to grouper

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a lot of information about the structure of your dataframe, so I will just assume a few things - please correct me if I'm wrong:

- A line with an entry in Col1 will never have an entry in Col2.
- Corresponding lines appear in the same sequence (lines 1,2,3... then
  corresponding lines 1,2,3...)
- Every line has a corresponding second line later on in the dataframe

If all those assumptions are correct, you could split your data into two dataframes, `df_upperhalf` containing the Col1, `df_lowerhalf` the Col2.

```
df_upperhalf = df.iloc[:len(df.index),]
df_lowerhalf = df.iloc[(len(df.index)*(-1):,]
```

Then you can easily combine those values:

```
df_combined = df_upperhalf
df_combined['Col2'] = df_lowerhalf['Col2']
```

If some of my assumptions are incorrect, this will of course not produce the results you want.

There are also quite a few ways to do it in fewer lines of code, but I think this way you end up with nicer dataframes and the code should be easily readable.

Edit:

I think this would be quite a bit faster:

```
df_upperhalf = df.head(len(df.index))
df_lowerhalf = df.tail(len(df.index))
```